# Vertically align text in a div surround by <a>

Tags: html, css

this is my first time on Stack Overflow, though I have found a lot of solutions here. But I couldn't find an answer to this question.
I made a div clickable by putting an `<a href>` around it and then inside the `<div>` tags I put the text. Here is the link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fw6HT/3/

I am sure that I am overlooking something really obvious, but I can't get the text to vertically align within the div. 

I hope you guys will be able to help me out!
I also stand open to other suggestions as to how to do this in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically will want to either

1. wrap the text in a DIV instead of a SPAN
2. or give the span "display: block" so you can manage it like a div

and then follow the rules here: [Vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fw6HT/4/)

```
div {
    background:red;
    top:50px;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

or if you have one line text

```
div {
    background:red;
    top:50px;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
}
```

but first solution is the best and common one

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, there's one super simple way to vertically and horizontally align any element within another element: [flexible box layout module](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Doesn't matter if you don't know the exact size of the content, doesn't matter if the container has a dynamic height/width.

All you need* is these three:

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fw6HT/7/)

*Of course, flexbox is a fairly new feature. It's [not available on older IEs](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) (well, not without a polyfill anyway) and it might require some browser prefixing too.

If you're not targeting older browsers and/or use something like [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer), flexbox is pretty damn awesome.